Android Studio Koala missing Network Inspector
I cannot find the Network Inspector on my fresh install of Android Studio Koala on a mac (Sonoma). I can open the App Profiler and start a session, but the tabs for Network Inspector and Database Inspector are missing, and I can't scroll down any further or see any messages that say Network Inspector moved. I don't see it in View > Tool Windows either. Is there something specific I have to do in AS or in my app to make the Network Inspector appear?

I've tried restarting the app, re-building and running the app, power cycling my device, and restarting AS with cache invalidation. I still can't find the Network Inspector.

Well, turns out I just made a pretty dumb mistake and confused the App Profiler with the App Inspector. I have to open the App Inspector tool window, and then I can see the Network Inspector, Database Inspector, and Background Task Inspector sub-windows/tabs. I'll leave this here in case anyone else gets mixed up like I did.
